# Maven default life cycle not recognized by mvn

Tags: java, maven

I'm used to use `mvn` for compilation, packaging, and so on. Reading more carefully through the documentation, I learned that `mvn` takes as argument either a life cycle, a phase, or a goal. The documentation also states that there are three built-in life cycles, namely `default`, `clean`, and `site`.

I can run `mvn clean` and `mvn site` but I cannot run `mvn default` , I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "default". You must specify a valid
> lifecycle phase or a goal ...

Am I missing something obvious? I read several documentations and can't find anyone mentioning that `mvn default` should not work, and why.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `mvn` with a life cycle as argument.

You can either use a phase or a goal.

A phase belongs to a life cycle. Running something like `mvn install` with run the default life cycle up to (and including) the phase `install`.